# Unexpected Token in IF Statement

Tags: powershell

I am trying to store a query result into a variable and use it in IF condition. However, it keeps failing with Unexpected Token in "eq" and ")".

What am I doing wrong?

I verified that all quotes are closed and in the ISE the code looks clean. 
It complains of a missing ")" in If statement, but it is there.

```
$ServerName='10.x.x.x'
$Database = 'MyDB'
$Value = 'Y'

$QueryResult =   Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerName -Database $Database -Query  "Select value from QcTable where appid=5;"

if ($QueryResult -eq $Value) {
 <<do that>>>
}
else {
  <<do this>>
 }
```

Expected program to go inside if block.

However error is thrown: 
Unexpected token 'eq' in expression or statement
Missing closing ')' after expression in 'If' statement.

EDIT: Removed "=" to Query. Still same result.

Comment: have you confirmed that the `-eq` is actually `<hyphen>eq`? sometimes copying from a webpage or a word doc will give a <em-dash> or an <en-dash> instead of a hyphen.

Comment: I typed it in. So the dash is the hyphen

Comment: kool! glad to get that cleared up ... and that PatrykMilewski had the real answer & fix. [*grin*]

Comment: What's the value of `$QueryResults`?

Comment: It is system.data.datarow. I changed it to $QueryResult | foreach{ $_.value } and it seems to work now. It prints the correct value and goes into the IF block. Its weird error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100 % sure, because I cannot recreate the exception, that you got, on my computer, but I think that the problem is here:

```
-Query = "Select value from QcTable where appid=5;"
       ^
       |
```

It may cause strange behaviours, try to remove this and check if it helps :)

**Edit:**

Since it doesn't help, there is another suggestion.

The code below works as expected:

```
$ServerName='10.x.x.x'
$Database = 'MyDB'
$Value = 'Y'

$QueryResult = echo 'Y'

if ($QueryResult -eq $Value) {
   echo $Value
   echo $ServerName
}
else {
   echo $Database
}
```

Output:

```
Y
10.x.x.x
```

Try, if it works the same, if it does, then I bet, that you've copied the code from pdf and there is something wrong with one of characters, for example:

```
$val = 1 ∕ 2
```

Gives error:

> [PowerShell] Unexpected token '∕' in expression or statement.

Because the  ∕  is Unicode char: U+2215 (DIVISION_SLASH), which is not the same as normal slash, which is U+002F (SLASH). Maybe you've got the same with equation symbol? Try to write this code by hand, and check if it helps.

If it still won't work out, then try to cut the code, until it works as expected, so you will be able to localise the source of problems.

Comment: Oh man. That will explain. Thanks so much. I'll remove it and try.

Comment: Unfortunately, no luck. Still the same error without the "="